# Pandas error with multidimensional key using .loc and a boolean

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, valueerror

Been running into this same error for 2 weeks, even though the code worked before. Not sure if I updated pandas as part of another library install, and maybe something changed there. Currently on version 23.4. Expected outcome is returning just the row with that identifier value.

```
In [42]: df.head()

Out[43]:

index   Identifier  ... 
0        51384710   ... 
1        74838J10   ... 
2        80589M10   ...     
3        67104410   ... 
4        50241310   ... 

[5 rows x 14 columns]
In [43]: df.loc[df.Identifier.isin(['51384710'])].head()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
        exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "<ipython-input-44-a3dbf43451ef>", line 1, in <module>
     df.loc[df.Identifier.isin(['51384710'])].head()
File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1478, in __getitem__
        return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1899, in _getitem_axis
        raise ValueError('Cannot index with multidimensional key')
    **ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key**
```

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu0VY.png)

Comment: `df.loc[df.Identifier.isin(['51384710'])].head()` is working for me

Answer (score 5):

Fixed it. I'd done df.columns = [column_list] where column_list = [...], which caused df to be treated as if it had a multiindex, even though there was only one level. removed the brackets from the df.columns assignment.

Comment: In my case it was I had duplicated the name of the column in the `column_list` variable, so, I changed the name for a different one. Example: I had "Category" twice, so, the solution for my case was chance those names as: "Category" and "Channel_Categories".

Answer (score -1):

Try changing

```
df.loc[df.Identifier.isin(['51384710'])].head()
```

to

```
df[df.Identifier.isin(['51384710'])].head()
```

Comment: When I don't use .loc I get:

     index   Identifier       ...     
     0         51384710     ...           
     1             NaN    ...          
     2             NaN    ...   
     3             NaN    ...    
     4             NaN    ...

Comment: this solves a similar problem of mine.